# What are the implications of having a bone token spellbook?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

I am working on a Wizard character that used the bone tokens mentioned in Complete Arcane as his spellbook, with the idea that he was a jeweler by trade and made special bone jewelery to store information for his spells, which he kept locked in a chest he carried in a bag of holding. Thing is, I seem to have inadvertently circumvented a good deal of the rules concerning various aspects of spellbook keeping, specifically page limits and pricing for pages. Other rules in complete arcane lead me to suspect a 1-page bone would cost somewhere between 1sp and 1cp, but that says little about their expected weight or how much one could fit in a standard Player's Handbook equipment chest (which by the way does not have a stated capacity, either). Does anyone have any further information that could help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Complete Arcane* says

> Scribing spells onto tokens requires the same expense in materials as for a standard
>   spellbook. An object holds anywhere from 1 to 9 page-equivalents of spellbook information, depending on its size. (187)

Thus it doesn't appear that you miss out on the joys of of spending 100 gp per page for materials for writing new spells into your spellbook (*PH* 179) just because you're using bones or rocks instead.

The difference is that instead of buying blank spellbooks (*PH* 129, 130) (15 gp; 3 lbs.) and writing spells into those, you save that money by flaying the flesh from your enemies and writing your spells on their bones or by finding cool rocks and writing on those.

It's a flavor thing for wizards who aren't bookish.

*Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* can't list prices and weights of every bone or rock; that must be a DM's call. A reasonable DM would probably price bones to make them cost as much as blank spellbooks for your convenience.

The spell *omen of peril* [div] (*SpC* 149) has as its focus "marked sticks, bones, or similar tokens worth at least 25 gp." Raw materials for making such a focus cost about 8 gp, and that's for a *set*. How many bones in a set? Unfortunately, the text doesn't say.

A chest, according to the spell *Leomund's secret chest* [conj] (*PH* 247), is 3 ft. x 2 ft. x 2 ft.

Comment: I know the price for spells doesn't change- I was asking more about what costs to expect for suitable bones, or if I could just get them for free off certain monsters (Acid spells to clean the flesh off, perhaps?). And there's still no mention of how much a chest should be able to carry, either.